# How to cap the network bandwidth for a program in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, bandwidth

In Linux, how can I cap the network bandwidth for a program (process)? For example, I would like to cap the network bandwidth for a.out to 20 Mbps. Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using [trickle](https://linux.die.net/man/1/trickle):

```
trickle -u 2500 -d 2500 a.out
```